# Telegram API with Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, telegram

I'm searching an example of [Telegram API](https://core.telegram.org/api) usage with Google Apps Script, or anyone/anything that can help me to learn how to use this API, for instance to send a message to a certain user

Comment: I'm sorry for the late reply. Is there a link for the API page(to avoid confusion). Are you trying to POST a simple JSON/HTTP query. I want to help you but I don't know how...

Comment: https://core.telegram.org/api

Comment: Posted it below as solution but it was deleted. To short or something..no time. really.: https://github.com/MeneerOom/Connect-Telegram-Bot-to-Google-Sheets

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was searching for something similar, and couldn't find any, so I have made my own, I will write it down here perhaps someone would make use of it.

This is a simple proof of concept that works:

```
function sendTelegramNotification(botSecret, chatId, body) {
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://api.telegram.org/bot" + botSecret + "/sendMessage?text=" + encodeURIComponent(body) + "&chat_id=" + chatId + "&parse_mode=HTML");
}
```

Other commands can be made same way.

Comment: You can get the botSecret or bot token using the bot father.

Answer (score 3):

I actively monitor Google Apps Script examples and I am not aware of samples integrating to the Telegram API. Given the [level of security encryption required with the Telegram API](https://core.telegram.org/mtproto/security_guidelines) I would suggest an integration with this service is unlikely due to Apps Script runtime limits.

I haven't found any examples to date of sending messages to a user but the Telegram service has posted large amounts of code, including their [web client code, on Github](https://github.com/zhukov/webogram) and this would seem to be the best starting point for now.

Update: Telegram have created a [Bot API](https://core.telegram.org/bots) which allows third party scripts to run in Telegram. The advantage of the Bot API is you don't need to do any message encryption. The [PHP code sample](https://core.telegram.org/bots/samples/hellobot) could easily be ported to Apps Script.