# G.A.S. code to email a google sheet as a pdf file to a person through Telegram

Tags: google-apps-script, pdf-generation, telegram, email-attachments

I use the following Google Script Code to generate a pdf of a google sheet and send it through email. Is there a way I can send the pdf through teleram to a person? How should I change the following code to send the pdf through telegram?

```
function emailReport() {
  readyForExport();
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var subject = spreadsheet.getRange("U1:U1").getValues();
  var emailTo = spreadsheet.getRange("V1:V1").getValues();
  var message = spreadsheet.getRange("W1:W1").getValues();
  var fileName = spreadsheet.getRange("X1:X1").getValues();
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Students"));
  var pdf = DriveApp.getFileById(spreadsheet.getId()).getAs('application/pdf').getBytes();
  var attach = {fileName:fileName[0][0],content:pdf, mimeType:'application/pdf'};
  MailApp.sendEmail(emailTo, subject, message, {attachments:[attach]});
};
```

Comment: You'll need to use the Telegram REST API and `UrlFetchApp`

Comment: @tehhowch So I guess I won't be able to do it because I am a novice and I am just manipulating existing codes I find online to fit my needs.

Comment: Is this information useful for you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21967762/telegram-api-with-google-apps-script

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Telegram API with Google Apps Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21967762/telegram-api-with-google-apps-script)

Comment: Thank you @Tanaike

Comment: Thank yu @tehhowch